# L2 Regularized Least Squares for Image Denoising

Tags: python, image-processing, mathematical-optimization, gradient-descent, least-squares

Let y be a noisy image described by the relationship y = x+n, where u is a noise-free image and n is the noise. The goal is to recover x from n.

min || y-x ||^2_2+lambda|| x ||^2_2

It should be solved by the gradient method for the optimization problem. Here is the code that I wrote, but I cannot get the correct answer. If anyone can help me, I would greatly appreciate it.

```
import numpy as np
import math
from PIL import Image
from skimage import  img_as_float
from skimage.util import random_noise
import math
from numpy import linalg as LA
from skimage.metrics import peak_signal_noise_ratio
import scipy.ndimage.filters

#define image
img = img_as_float(np.random.random((2, 2)))
#define noise
noise = np.random.normal(0,1,size=(2,2))*0.2
#add noise to image
img_noise=img+noise

p = 0.0001  #gradient step
N = 600 #number of iterations 
Lambda = 5
Cur_u = img_noise
weight_history = []
print('img=',img)
for k in range(N):
  Prev_u=Cur_u
  Cur_u = Prev_u - p*(2*(Prev_u-img_noise)+2*Lambda*Prev_u)
  weight_history.append(Cur_u)
  [enter image description here][1]

print(weight_history)
psnr = peak_signal_noise_ratio(img,img_noise)
psnr = peak_signal_noise_ratio(img,weight_history[-1])
```

I want that the denoising image becomes more closer to the original image. But I do not see any denoising. I cannot see any difference between noise and denoising. I use psnr and it shows that no change happens. I change learning rate and iteration but I do not see any correct result.

Comment: I guess the code snippet doesn't really need that whole daunting list of imports.  Anyway it might be easier for more people to help if you could explain the gradient method you are trying to implement, and ideally give a link to a reference for it.  Also, it would help to show what result you get and what you want to get.

Comment: @TMBailey
I remove extra import. it does not allow to me attach image. I explain what I expect for result.

Comment: Can't you just `print` the arrays `img`, `noise`, and `img_noise`?

Comment: @TMBailey
Thank you for your help!
img=array([[0.97451233, 0.91541228],
       [0.88199456, 0.71679863]])
noise=array([[ 0.00986225, -0.02861475],
       [ 0.37150991, -0.08547853]])
img_noise=array([[0.98437458, 0.88679753],
       [1.25350448, 0.6313201 ]])

Comment: _y = x+n, where u …_ - There is no _u_ in _y = x+n_.

Answer (score 2):

You current denoising model just dumps the values of the image toward zero.
For effective denoising you need a better model.

A simple model is assuming that an image is piece wise constant signal (See [Why Sparse Priors Like Total Variation Opts to Concentrate Derivatives at a Small Number of Pixels](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/29807)).

So a better model, basically the MAP of such assumption is given by:

$$ \frac{1}{2} {\left| \boldsymbol{x} - \boldsymbol{y} \right|}_{2}^{2} + \frac{\lambda}{2} {\left| \boldsymbol{D} \boldsymbol{x} \right|}_{2}^{2} $$

[image]

Where $\boldsymbol{D}$ is the derivative operator.
The parameter $\lambda$ controls the amount of denoising.

**Remark**: It is even better to use L1 regularization, yet it requires different machinery to solve.

The gradient is given by:

$$ \boldsymbol{x} - \boldsymbol{y} + \lambda \boldsymbol{D}^{T} \boldsymbol{D} \boldsymbol{x} $$

[image]